# Setting minimum size limit for a window in java swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jframe

I have a **JFrame** which has **3 JPanels** in **GridBagLayout**..

Now, when I minimize a windows, after a certain limit, the third JPanel tends to disappear.
I tried setting minimizing size of JFrame using **setMinimumSize(new Dimension(int,int))** but no success. The windows can still be minimized.

> So, I actually want to make a threshhold, that my window cannot be minimized after a certain limit.

How can I do so?

Code:-

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also:

```
shadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~/java$ java --showversion
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.1

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Usage: gij [OPTION] ... CLASS [ARGS] ...
          to invoke CLASS.main, or
       gij -jar [OPTION] ... JARFILE [ARGS] ...
          to execute a jar file
Try `gij --help' for more information.
shadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~/java$
```

Gives me output like

[image]
<sub>(source: [abhijeet1989 at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/abhijeet1989/OMG3.png))</sub>

**UPDATE: ** The same when run though Netbeans IDE gives expected output.. When I run through "java JFrameExample" compiler, I am facing issues.. Now, what that means??

Comment: What platform are you on, and what version of Java are you using?

Comment: do you know the specific update number of your java 6? Type 'java -version' and you should see something like: java version "1.6.0_18", 18 would be the update #. It's possible there is a bug that is only fixed in a later version of java 6

Comment: On top of that, could you edit your post to give us a small example of your code, so you show us the problem.

Comment: I just copy and pasted your code and ran it. Same issue happened.. I am still having the same problem..

Comment: Issue solved... I was using java 1.5.0.. while netbeans is using java 1.6.0_20.. So, the new version solved the issue..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setMinimumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) tells me, that this behavior is platform dependent. Especially, since the following example code works for me as desired in Windows Vista:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me as well (on Ubuntu 9, java 6, gnome).

Comment: I am on ubuntu 9.10,java 6, Gnome.. Its not working for me.. I hope you are sure about my question. I dont want my windows to be minimized after a certain threshold...

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04, Java 7, Gnome/Unity.

Comment: Works on macOS 10.15, Java 14

Answer (score 13):

There actually is a way to ensure minimum size on any platform. You need to set the minimum size of the JFrame to the minimum size of its content pane and then you need to write a ComponentAdapter and override componentResized. Then you just use getSize and getMinimum size on your JFrame and substitute width and/or height with the minimum width or height if it is greater. Assuming you are extending JFrame:

```
this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
            Dimension d=YourJFrame.this.getSize();
            Dimension minD=YourJFrame.this.getMinimumSize();
            if(d.width<minD.width)
                d.width=minD.width;
            if(d.height<minD.height)
                d.height=minD.height;
            YourJFrame.this.setSize(d);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
         @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
                Dimension d= frame.getSize();
                Dimension minD=frame.getMinimumSize();
                if(d.width<minD.width)
                    d.width=minD.width;
                if(d.height<minD.height)
                    d.height=minD.height;
                frame.setSize(d);
            }
        });`
 <br/> 
Where frame is declared as class member `private JFrame frame;`

[Demo Code, need to download](https://ideone.com/i9AYBf)