# User Defined Exception, Re-sizing

Tags: java, exception, event-handling, jframe, jpanel

I am currently trying to code my program that uses a JFrame and JPanel so that if the user tries to re-size the Frame smaller than the Panel the program won't allow that to happen. I've been researching for a while now using and got it working a little bit with a ComponentListener however I need to code it using a user-defined exception. Below is the code I used for the ComponentListener. Could anyone give me advice on how to do this via a User-Defined exception?

```
Frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() 
{
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) 
    {
        Frame.setSize(Math.min(800,
        Frame.getWidth()),
        Math.min(350,
        Frame.getHeight()));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Swing supports preventing users from resizing with the `setMinimumSize` function on `JFrame`.

See [Setting minimum size limit for a window in java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781939/setting-minimum-size-limit-for-a-window-in-java-swing)

Comment: So would I just make a new class for my user defined exception? then make a method in it for Frame.setMinimumSize(200,200);

Comment: You do not need to define an Exception, please see the link.

Comment: Hm. Now I'm confused then why I would be asked to use a user-defined exception to handle this if a function already exists in the swing library.